# Navigationview tabpanel, sub-tabpanel

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to have a subtabpanel in a tab panel. I did red some answers but not quite understood :(

Here for example, how can I heva tab 3, 4 and 5 appears with a back button on top when I click on tab 3 ? (everything I did : Tab 1, 2 and 3 stays there...)

Thanks :)

**Main.js :**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyNavigationView', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',

    config: {
        ui: 'light',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                title: 'MyTabPanel1',
                layout: {
                    animation: 'fade',
                    type: 'card'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        title: 'Tab 1',
                        iconCls: 'info'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        title: 'Tab 2',
                        iconCls: 'info'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        title: 'Tab 3',
                        iconCls: 'info'
                    }
                ],
                tabBar: {
                    docked: 'bottom'
                }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                title: 'MyTabPanel',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        title: 'Tab 3',
                        iconCls: 'info'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        title: 'Tab 4',
                        iconCls: 'info'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        title: 'Tab 5',
                        iconCls: 'info'
                    }
                ],
                tabBar: {
                    docked: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        ]
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you push at once two tab panel into navigation view. But for first time you need only show first panel. For this you need add into navigation view only first panel. The second panel you need  add to navigation view only when user choose third tab on first tabPanel. For this you should listen 'acitveitemchange'  event and determine than 3 tab became active. Then push second tab pane.

Look this example

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyNavigationView', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',

    config: {
        ui: 'light',
        autoDestroy: false

    },

    constructor : function(){
        this.callParent(arguments);

        this.firstTabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel',{
            title: 'MyTabPanel1',
            layout: {
                animation: 'fade',
                type: 'card'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    title: 'Tab 1',
                    iconCls: 'info',
                    html : 'TAB 1'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    title: 'Tab 2',
                    iconCls: 'info',
                    html : 'TAB 2'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    title: 'Tab 3',
                    iconCls: 'info',
                    html : 'TAB 3'
                }
            ],
            tabBar: {
                docked: 'bottom'
            }
        });

        this.secondTabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel',{
            title: 'MyTabPanel',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    title: 'Tab 3',
                    iconCls: 'info',
                    html : 'TAB 3'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    title: 'Tab 4',
                    iconCls: 'info',
                    html : 'TAB 4'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    title: 'Tab 5',
                    iconCls: 'info',
                    html : 'TAB 5'
                }
            ],
            tabBar: {
                docked: 'bottom'
            }
        });

        this.firstTabPanel.on('activeitemchange', this.tabPanel1ActiveItemChange, this);

        //show first tab panel
        this.push(this.firstTabPanel);
    },

    tabPanel1ActiveItemChange : function(tabpanel, newtab){
        //if newtab is third tab than show second tab panel
        if(this.firstTabPanel.getInnerItems().indexOf(newtab)=== 2){
            this.push(this.secondTabPanel);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Would you mind explainin how to do the samething on item tap or item diclosure ? For example, if the third tab has a list, then show tabpanel2 when clicking on item1, tabpanel3 when clicking on item2. Thanks.

Comment: I did ask here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547472/navigationview-tabpanel-sub-tabpanel-when-clicking-an-item